# Containing a DomPDF text object within an area

Tags: php, dompdf

I've been using DomPDF to create a dynamically created PDF, and I've stumbled upon a problem that I can't figure out.

Is there a way to give the object a width and height so that the text automatically wraps in the area provided? I've had a look at the documentation but there's nothing that I can find that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got around this by taking the string, and splitting it to a certain length then using the text object to insert each line in one by one.